# 96 honda accord wont start

Tags: honda, starting, accord, vtec

So I was having trouble with my 96 accord it was sputtering and Hesitant replaced plugs and wires checked my EGR it was good then suddenly out of nowhere it stalled out on me while driving and now it won't start it acts like it wants to but it won't turn over I smacked the starter a few times this is the first time its happened

Comment: Do you have an automatic or manual transmission? If it's a manual you may be able to push-start it to eliminate starting system issues.

Comment: No unfortunately it's a automatic

Comment: When you say, "*It won't turn over*" do you mean it isn't firing? To me when you say "*it acts like it wants to*", you are saying the engine turns over but doesn't quite catch to run. Also, how many miles on the car? When was the last time the timing belt was changed?

Comment: Are you getting a click from the solenoid next to the starter when you put the key into the START position? Also, do you know what your battery voltage is? Have you checked your battery and starter wiring connections?

Comment: I unfortunately can't hear anything cause I am the only person here and alot of traffic... ( I'm stranded) just replaced my battery It acts like it wants to turn over and start but it just don't

Comment: Have you ever started the car on this new battery?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the previous comment I just got the car I haven't actually had the timing looked at yet but yes it don't want to catch I'm not the best when it comes to diagnosing a car problem......

Comment: Yeah it ran for two weeks had everything checked out everything but the battery was good

Comment: Almost like its not getting gas

Comment: Is the fuel tank empty?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the engine will rotate on a start attempt but will not start and run. On this model the most common cause of this symptom is failure of the ignition coil or ignition igniter. Located in the distributor on most models these parts make the spark that ends up at the spark plugs. Fuel supply problems are not common on this model. The next step in testing is to see the engine is getting spark and fuel, most likely it will be found to be a lack of spark problem.  Other less common failure are the main relay and ignition switch.

Comment: Actually I found the problem it was the timing belt